# How to pass a user variable saved in forms to a button link in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get a user to enter the IP address, and then return the user this IP address with port attached as a button that  can be clicked by this user and take him to given website ( a part of bigger project ). I have the IP address saved, but when I'm trying to pass it, I'm getting errors.

views.py:

```
@login_required
def home(request):                            
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ConnectionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            home.ip = form.cleaned_data['ip']   
            home.username = form.cleaned_data['username'] 
            home.password = form.cleaned_data['password'] 
            return redirect('deploy_honeypot')      
    else:
        form = ConnectionForm()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

and in template:

```
<td><a href="{{ url 'home.ip' }}">Your Website</a></td>
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Connection



class ConnectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ConnectionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['ip'].label = "IP address of your server"
        self.fields['password'].widget = forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Password'
            }
        )
       

    class Meta:
        model = Connection
        fields = ('ip', 'username', 'password')
 


    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ConnectionForm, self).clean()
        ip = cleaned_data.get('ip')
        username = cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')
        if not ip and not username and not password:
            raise forms.ValidationError('You have to fill in all fields!')
```

Comment: please add form(`ConnectionForm`), url and template for more clarification

Comment: Added above. Nothing in the template really, that is corresponds to this part of code yet

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the '%' and it should be a single curly bracket.
It should be :

```
<td><a href="{% url 'home.ip' %}">Your Website</a></td>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had it before, just forgot to add it now. It stiil returns error:    ```TemplateSyntaxError at /iot/
Could not parse the remainder: '% url 'home.ip' %' from '% url 'home.ip' %'```

Comment: use only single curly bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Found a reason:

```
ipaddress = home.ip
return render(request, 'template.html', {'ipaddress' : ipaddress })
```

I wasn't passing the parameter correctly.